# Warning about tautological compares inhibited by const?

Tags: c++, gcc, warnings, clang

The following piece of code generates warnings on both GCC and Clang:

```c
int main() {
  unsigned n = 0;
  return ( n < 0 ) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

The warnings are:

```
$ g++-4.7 -std=c++11 -O3 -Wall -Wextra t.cc -o t
t.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
t.cc:3:16: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtype-limits]
$ clang++-3.2 -std=c++11 -O3 -Wall -Wextra t.cc -o t
t.cc:3:14: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtautological-compare]
  return ( n < 0 ) ? 1 : 0;
           ~ ^ ~
1 warning generated.
$
```

So far, so good. Now I change the variable to be `const`:

```c
int main() {
  const unsigned n = 0;
  return ( n < 0 ) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

And both compilers are suddenly happy to compile the code without warnings:

```
$ g++-4.7 -std=c++11 -O3 -Wall -Wextra t.cc -o t
$ clang++-3.2 -std=c++11 -O3 -Wall -Wextra t.cc -o t
$
```

**QUESTION:** Why does this happen? Is there a **reason**, why `const` variables suppress the warning? If both GCC and Clang agree, I hesitate to just throw a bug-report at them as it seems more likely that I need to learn something :)

**EDIT:** The constant folding of the compiler might have to do with it, but it is *not sufficient to explain the behaviour*. In the first example (without the `const`), the compiler *does* know the value and that it never changes. I checked the assembler output and the compiler does do constant folding but it **still** generates the warning, probably *before* it replaces the variable by the known constant when it sees the expression `( n < 0 )` and knowing that `n` is an unsigned type. That said: Why does this behaviour changes when I add `const`? I think that if the first example produces a warning, it should also be possible to generate a warning for the second.

Comment: It's just a side-effect of compiler optimizations.

Comment: The same happens with `-O0`.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Some optimizations are applied even without optimizations. In this case, the compiler is literally copy/pasting the constant into all the places it is used.

Comment: Offtopic comment : I liked Clang warning flag.  The option `-Wtautological-compare` is better phrased than `-Wtypes-limits`.

Comment: Try a function `foo` with `n` as an argument (`const` and not)

Comment: The behavior is similar as if `const unsigned n = 0` was a `#define`. Does the `O3` optimizes `const`s into defines?

Comment: @Avio: It can't, as the preprocessor runs before the compiler.

Comment: No, a const will never be turned into a `#define` - but the const will be replaced by its value in the expression evaluation. It probably does this even at `-O0`

Answer (score 6):

It's an explicit constant -- your *intent*. Your desired warning is effectively transferred from:

```
warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtautological-compare]
return ( n < 0 ) ? 1 : 0;
         ~ ^ ~
```

to `-Wunreachable-code` when `const`:

```
warning: will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
return ( n < 0 ) ? 1 : 0;
                   ^
```

Note: `-Wtautological-compare` warnings may still be emitted by the compiler where values are not known.

Answer (score 2):

When the variable is not `const`, it might change, the compiler doesn't know it. That's why there is a warning. If it is `const`, it will never change. That way, the compiler can replace any occurence of `n` with the actual value of `n`, in this case:

```
return ( 0 < 0 ) ? 1 : 0;
-> return 0;
```

Hence, no warning.